# Метод, возвращающий struct

Tags: c, xcode, objective-c, iphone

В техническом описании решения задачи встречается следующая цитата:

> В .m нужно создать два метода. Один для вычисления нормы БЖУ пользователя (для этого завести struct БЖУ, которую будет возвращать метод) и один для вычисления нормы воды

Вопрос: каким образом метод может возвращать `struct` как результат? Может он должен передаваться ему как аргумент? Если да, то как тогда может выглядеть сигнатура метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А в чем собственно проблема? Обьявляете где-нибудь структуру struct BGU{} и смело можете объявлять метод:

```
-(struct BGU) myMetod;
```

И все будет хорошо, можете еще typedef сделать. А вообще таких структур в обж-си полно, особенно в CoreCraphics (всякие CGRect, CGPoint, CGSize)

Comment: спасибо за комментарий!

Comment: позвольте еще вопрос. Что в данном случае метод должен возвратить?  То есть что писать после return?

Comment: структуру и пишите, что то типа -(struct BGU) myMetod{struct BGU bgu; bgu.a=109; bgu.b=11; rerurn bgu }

Comment: понял, спасибо!